# Is this a valid way to code up an MVC Service Layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC service layer I have code such as the following to validate:

```
protected bool ValidateAccount(Account account)
        {
            var accounts = _accountRepository.GetPk(account.PartitionKey);
            if (accounts.Any(b => b.Title.Equals(account.Title) &&
                                  !b.RowKey.Equals(account.RowKey)))
                _validationDictionary.AddError("", "Duplicate title");
            return _validationDictionary.IsValid;
        }
```

However in the "action type" methods I absorb exceptions with code like this:

```
public bool Create(Account account)
{
    if (!ValidateAccount(account))
        return false;
    try
    {
        _accountRepository.AddOrUpdate(account);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My controller is coded like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(BaseViewModel vm)
{
    _accountService = new AccountService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState), vm.Meta.DataSourceID);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

            _accountService = new AccountService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState), vm.Meta.DataSourceID);
            if (!_accountService.Create(vm.Account))
                return View("CreateEdit", vm);
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Created");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Home");
    }
    return View("CreateEdit", vm);
}
```

Is this a reasonable approach to take? My one concern is that I might be losing exception information in the service layer.

Answer (score 3):

You should at the very least **log** your exception somewhere (event log, file system, using [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), etc).

The problem with your code is that you'll never know if something bad happened in production environment or you won't be able to discover what failed exactly (just that the code returned false).

Plus, you should never handle all exceptions like you do (unfiltered catch) but only the one you can revert back to a normal state. It's far better to let the application crash than to keep it online unstable.

> Avoid handling errors by catching non-specific exceptions, such as System.Exception, System.SystemException, and so on, in application code. There are cases when handling errors in applications is acceptable, but such cases are rare.

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx) on best practices for handling exceptions and [Design Guidelines for Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014.aspx)

Comment: +1 it's never a good idea to do a general catch-all as could be masking an even bigger problem. The general rule of thumb is catch what you can, let the rest bubble up.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not doing anything with the exception in your Create method in the service layer, I would suggest removing the try/catch from it.

I would still return true or false to indicate whether the create operation was successful. I will however add a try/catch in the caller to make sure exceptions are handled. In your case that could be in your controller action (or the OnException in your base controller.)

Another approach is to leave the try/catch in your Create method but as @Stephane suggested do something with it (like log it) but you could also log it wherever you catch it.